# Postgres service on windows timing out before DB starts

Tags: windows, postgresql-12

I have a PostgreSQL 12 server on a Windows VM. After a machine restart, the service attempted to start but timed out, returning a pg_ctl timeout error in the event logs. However the DB started under the hood and is accessible to users.

Unfortunately, using a pg_ctl status on the data directory still shows no postgres running, despite the postmaster files present in that directory and the DB being accessible and queryable.

How can I soft stop the database so I can try to bring it up again using pg_ctl and get them back in sync?

I have tried a machine restart and checking the status using pg_ctl, but am reluctant to stop the individual postgres processes in case of causing bigger problems.